# Is there a temporary fix possible to compile successfully working ffmpeg for the windows 10 using MinGW?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-10, mingw, deprecated, advapi32

Current ffmpeg depends on CryptAcquireContextW what was deprecated and now removed from Windows. It compiles fine, but on running it crashes with text: "ffmpeg procedure entry point CryptAcquireContextW could not be located in the dynamic link library". advapi32 does not provide it anymore? The net say's it is deprecated already for a  longer, however latest stable 4.3.git ffmpeg still depends on it.
Is there a temporary fix possible to compile successfully working ffmpeg for the windows 10 using MinGW?

Comment: There's no issue in compiling ffmpeg on Windows 10 using mingw. Share your build env and toolchain details.

Comment: Please read fully my question. It compiles fine, but it crash on running. Successfully compiled means it must run also fine.

Comment: Environment is default what media-autobuild_suite provides for a years: https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite

Comment: The compiled binary runs fine as well on Win10.

Comment: If you add --enable-cuda-sdk  and --enable-nonfree it fails to make final exe good. The error is not obviously related to the choice. It compiles fine but not works later. Also it implies cuda sdk is installed. Maybe that is what makes it wrong.